# Ansible loop through csv file elements

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

**sample.csv:**

```
table_name,column_name,prefix
segment_100,test1:null:string,x:y/1:z/1
segment_100,test2_name:null:string,p:q/1
segment_101,test3_name:null:string,foo
```

**Ansible Playbook:**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

 - name: Read CSV file
   read_csv:
     path: sample.csv
   register: vms

 - debug:
     msg: "{{vms.list}}"

 - name: Run shell command for each prefix
   debug:
     msg: "Running shell command for table -> {{item.0.table_name}} in column -> {{item.0.column_name}} for prefix -> {{item.1}}"
   with_nested:
     - "{{vms.list}}"
     - "{{vms.list[0].prefix.split(':')}}"
```

**Note:** I am currently using `"{{vms.list[0].prefix.split(':')"` which loads the first item in the list just to depict the scenario but ideally it is suppose to be a loop respective to each table and column.

**Output:**

```
TASK [Read CSV file] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "column_name": "test1:null:string",
            "prefix": "x:y/1:z/1",
            "table_name": "segment_100"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "test2_name:null:string",
            "prefix": "p:q/1",
            "table_name": "segment_100"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "test3_name:null:string",
            "prefix": "foo",
            "table_name": "segment_101"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Run shell command for each prefix] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'x:y/1:z/1', u'table_name': u'segment_100', u'column_name': u'test1:null:string'}, u'x']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test1:null:string for prefix -> x"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'x:y/1:z/1', u'table_name': u'segment_100', u'column_name': u'test1:null:string'}, u'y/1']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test1:null:string for prefix -> y/1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'x:y/1:z/1', u'table_name': u'segment_100', u'column_name': u'test1:null:string'}, u'z/1']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test1:null:string for prefix -> z/1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'p:q/1', u'table_name': u'segment_100', u'column_name': u'test2_name:null:string'}, u'x']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test2_name:null:string for prefix -> x"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'p:q/1', u'table_name': u'segment_100', u'column_name': u'test2_name:null:string'}, u'y/1']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test2_name:null:string for prefix -> y/1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'p:q/1', u'table_name': u'segment_100', u'column_name': u'test2_name:null:string'}, u'z/1']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test2_name:null:string for prefix -> z/1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'foo', u'table_name': u'segment_101', u'column_name': u'test3_name:null:string'}, u'x']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_101 in column -> test3_name:null:string for prefix -> x"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'foo', u'table_name': u'segment_101', u'column_name': u'test3_name:null:string'}, u'y/1']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_101 in column -> test3_name:null:string for prefix -> y/1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'foo', u'table_name': u'segment_101', u'column_name': u'test3_name:null:string'}, u'z/1']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_101 in column -> test3_name:null:string for prefix -> z/1"
}
```

**Scenario:**

I have a need to run a shell script for each of the **"prefix"** value (separated by a colon) corresponding to each **"table_name"** & **"column_name"**

**Desired Output:**

```
TASK [Run shell command for each prefix] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'x:y/1:z/1', u'table_name': u'segment_100', u'column_name': u'test1:null:string'}, u'x']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test1:null:string for prefix -> x"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'x:y/1:z/1', u'table_name': u'segment_100', u'column_name': u'test1:null:string'}, u'y/1']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test1:null:string for prefix -> y/1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'x:y/1:z/1', u'table_name': u'segment_100', u'column_name': u'test1:null:string'}, u'z/1']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test1:null:string for prefix -> z/1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'p:q/1', u'table_name': u'segment_100', u'column_name': u'test2_name:null:string'}, u'p']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test2_name:null:string for prefix -> p"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'p:q/1', u'table_name': u'segment_100', u'column_name': u'test2_name:null:string'}, u'q/1']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test2_name:null:string for prefix -> q/1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'prefix': u'foo', u'table_name': u'segment_101', u'column_name': u'test3_name:null:string'}, u'foo']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_101 in column -> test3_name:null:string for prefix -> foo"
}
```

Basically, I am looking to run shell script for each **prefix** string (colon separated) for each line item of CSV.

**Note**: I'm currently using the following Ansible version

```
$ ansible --version
  ansible 2.9.9
   config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
   configured module search path = [u'/xyz/users/test/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
   ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
   executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
   python version = 2.7.5 (default, May 27 2022, 11:27:32)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fore-note: **You are using an outdated and unsupported Ansible version which needs to be upgraded ASAP. Please see the [support matrix](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#ansible-core-support-matrix)**. The solution I give below is for recent versions of ansible. I gave a workaround for ansible 2.9 at the bottom of this post.

---

Transform the colon seperated prefix to list:

```yaml
prefixes: "{{ ['prefix: '] | ansible.builtin.product(vms.list | map(attribute='prefix') | map('split', ':')) | map('join') | map('from_yaml') }}"
```

Gives:

```json
{
    "prefixes": [
        {
            "prefix": [
                "x",
                "y/1",
                "z/1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "prefix": [
                "p",
                "q/1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "prefix": [
                "foo"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Combine those with the initial list from csv:

```yaml
vms_data: "{{ vms.list | zip(prefixes) | map('combine') }}"
```

gives:

```json
{
    "vms_data": [
        {
            "column_name": "test1:null:string",
            "prefix": [
                "x",
                "y/1",
                "z/1"
            ],
            "table_name": "segment_100"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "test2_name:null:string",
            "prefix": [
                "p",
                "q/1"
            ],
            "table_name": "segment_100"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "test3_name:null:string",
            "prefix": [
                "foo"
            ],
            "table_name": "segment_101"
        }
    ]
}
```

Loop on that data structure with the `subelements` filter. Here is a full playbook to test:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    prefixes: "{{ ['prefix: '] | ansible.builtin.product(vms.list | map(attribute='prefix') | map('split', ':')) | map('join') | map('from_yaml') }}"
    vms_data: "{{ vms.list | zip(prefixes) | map('combine') }}"
    

  tasks:

    - name: Read CSV file
      ansible.builtin.read_csv:
        path: sample.csv
      register: vms

    - name: Run shell command for each prefix
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Running shell command for table -> {{ item.0.table_name }} in column -> {{ item.0.column_name }} for prefix -> {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ vms_data | subelements('prefix') }}"
```

which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook csv_loop.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Read CSV file] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Run shell command for each prefix] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'table_name': 'segment_100', 'column_name': 'test1:null:string', 'prefix': ['x', 'y/1', 'z/1']}, 'x']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test1:null:string for prefix -> x"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'table_name': 'segment_100', 'column_name': 'test1:null:string', 'prefix': ['x', 'y/1', 'z/1']}, 'y/1']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test1:null:string for prefix -> y/1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'table_name': 'segment_100', 'column_name': 'test1:null:string', 'prefix': ['x', 'y/1', 'z/1']}, 'z/1']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test1:null:string for prefix -> z/1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'table_name': 'segment_100', 'column_name': 'test2_name:null:string', 'prefix': ['p', 'q/1']}, 'p']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test2_name:null:string for prefix -> p"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'table_name': 'segment_100', 'column_name': 'test2_name:null:string', 'prefix': ['p', 'q/1']}, 'q/1']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_100 in column -> test2_name:null:string for prefix -> q/1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'table_name': 'segment_101', 'column_name': 'test3_name:null:string', 'prefix': ['foo']}, 'foo']) => {
    "msg": "Running shell command for table -> segment_101 in column -> test3_name:null:string for prefix -> foo"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Workaround for outdated Ansible versions where the filter `split` does not exist, where `list` is mandatory to get a list out of `map` and which might not fully support FQCNs (fully qualified collection names) **<= Please upgrade to a [supported version](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#ansible-core-support-matrix) ASAP**

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Read CSV file
      read_csv:
        path: sample.csv
      register: vms

    - name: Compute prefixes to perform combination
      set_fact:
        vms_data: >-
          {{
            vms_data | d([])
            +
            [item | combine({'prefix': item.prefix.split(':')})]
          }}
      loop: "{{ vms.list }}"

    - name: Run shell command for each prefix
      debug:
        msg: "Running shell command for table -> {{ item.0.table_name }} in column -> {{ item.0.column_name }} for prefix -> {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ vms_data | subelements('prefix') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the *prefixes* list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.table_name }} {{ '%-22s' % (item.0.column_name) }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ vms.list|zip(prefixes)|map('combine') }}"
        - prefix
      vars:
        prefixes: "{{ vms.list|
                      map(attribute='prefix')|
                      map('split', ':')|
                      map('community.general.dict_kv', 'prefix') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: segment_100 test1:null:string      x
  msg: segment_100 test1:null:string      y/1
  msg: segment_100 test1:null:string      z/1
  msg: segment_100 test2_name:null:string p
  msg: segment_100 test2_name:null:string q/1
  msg: segment_101 test3_name:null:string foo
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/sample.csv
      register: vms

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.table_name }} {{ '%-22s' % (item.0.column_name) }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ vms.list|zip(prefixes)|map('combine') }}"
        - prefix
      vars:
        prefixes: "{{ vms.list|
                      map(attribute='prefix')|
                      map('split', ':')|
                      map('community.general.dict_kv', 'prefix') }}"
```

Comment: Hello @Vladimir Botka. Thanks for the solution. How would this work when there are multiple CSV files which would change the data structure to build?

Here is the complete context -> [ansible-loop-through-csv-elements-for-multiple-csv-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75802699/ansible-loop-through-csv-elements-for-multiple-csv-files)