# Ansible loop through CSV elements for multiple CSV files

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

This is an enhancement to solution provided by @zeitounator [Ansible loop through csv file elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75747793/ansible-loop-through-csv-file-elements).

Whereas the existing solution works for a single CSV file, the list structure changes when there are multiple CSV files involved. For example,

**Directory Structure:**

`/tmp/test/foo`

```
  csv1/
    sample.csv
  csv2/
    sample.csv
```

**Command:** `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e "csv=csv1,csv2"`

**Playbook Modification:**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: Read CSV file
      read_csv:
        path: "/tmp/test/foo/{{ item }}/sample.csv"
      with_items: "{{ csv.split(',') }}"
      register: vms

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
       loop: "{{ vms.results | json_query('[].list') }}"

    - name: Compute prefixes to perform combination
        set_fact:
      vms_data: "{{ vms_data | default([]) + [item | combine({'prefix': item.prefix.split(':')})] }}"
      loop: "{{ vms.results | json_query('[].list') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ vms_data }}"

    - name: Run shell command for each prefix
      debug:
        msg: "Running shell command for table -> {{ item.0.table_name }} in column -> {{ item.0.column_name }} for prefix -> {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ vms_data | subelements('prefix') }}"
```

I have been trying to use JSON query to get the list to pass it to `Compute prefixes to perform combination` task but not getting the desired result. I believe `JSON query` parsing `item` is passing the same structure to the task as the one in the parent solution (link above)

**Error:**

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'prefix'
```

What am I missing? Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I had to put the JSON query list into `with_items` instead of `loop` at `Compute prefixes to perform combination` task to solve this.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: Read CSV file
      read_csv:
        path: "/tmp/test/foo/{{ item }}/sample.csv"
      with_items: "{{ csv.split(',') }}"
      register: vms

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ vms.results | json_query('[].list') }}"

    - name: Compute prefixes to perform combination
      set_fact:
        vms_data: "{{ vms_data | default([]) + [item | combine({'prefix': item.prefix.split(':')})] }}"
      with_items: "{{ vms.results | json_query('[].list') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ vms_data }}"

    - name: Run shell command for each prefix
      debug:
         msg: "Running shell command for table -> {{ item.0.table_name }} in column -> {{ item.0.column_name }} for prefix -> {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ vms_data | subelements('prefix') }}"
```

Comment: [`with_items: "{{ some_list }}"` is equivalent to `loop: "{{ some_list | flatten(levels=1) }}"`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items)

Answer (score 0):

Given the files for testing

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/test/
/tmp/test/
├── csv1
│   └── sample.csv
└── csv2
    └── sample.csv

2 directories, 2 files
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test/csv1/sample.csv 
table_name,column_name,prefix
segment_100,test1:null:string,x:y/1:z/1
segment_100,test2_name:null:string,p:q/1
segment_101,test3_name:null:string,foo
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test/csv2/sample.csv 
table_name,column_name,prefix
segment_200,test1:null:string,x:y/1:z/1
segment_200,test2_name:null:string,p:q/1
segment_201,test3_name:null:string,foo
```

Read the files

```yaml
    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/test/{{ item }}/sample.csv
      loop: [csv1, csv2]
      register: vms
```

and create the list prefixes

```yaml
  prefixes: "{{ vms.results|
                map(attribute='list')|
                map('map', attribute='prefix')|
                map('map', 'split', ':')|
                map('map', 'community.general.dict_kv', 'prefix')|
                list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  prefixes:
    - - prefix: [x, y/1, z/1]
      - prefix: [p, q/1]
      - prefix: [foo]
    - - prefix: [x, y/1, z/1]
      - prefix: [p, q/1]
      - prefix: [foo]
```

You have to combine the prefixes in a template because it is not possible to *map* the function *zip*

```yaml
  vms_prefixes_str: |
    {% for i in vms.results|map(attribute='list')|zip(prefixes) %}
    - {{ i.0|zip(i.1)|map('combine')|list }}
    {% endfor %}
  vms_prefixes: "{{ vms_prefixes_str|from_yaml|flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  vms_prefixes:
    - column_name: test1:null:string
      prefix: [x, y/1, z/1]
      table_name: segment_100
    - column_name: test2_name:null:string
      prefix: [p, q/1]
      table_name: segment_100
    - column_name: test3_name:null:string
      prefix: [foo]
      table_name: segment_101
    - column_name: test1:null:string
      prefix: [x, y/1, z/1]
      table_name: segment_200
    - column_name: test2_name:null:string
      prefix: [p, q/1]
      table_name: segment_200
    - column_name: test3_name:null:string
      prefix: [foo]
      table_name: segment_201
```

Now you can iterate the list with subelements

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.table_name }} {{ '%-22s' % (item.0.column_name) }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ vms_prefixes }}"
        - prefix
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: segment_100 test1:null:string      x
  msg: segment_100 test1:null:string      y/1
  msg: segment_100 test1:null:string      z/1
  msg: segment_100 test2_name:null:string p
  msg: segment_100 test2_name:null:string q/1
  msg: segment_101 test3_name:null:string foo
  msg: segment_200 test1:null:string      x
  msg: segment_200 test1:null:string      y/1
  msg: segment_200 test1:null:string      z/1
  msg: segment_200 test2_name:null:string p
  msg: segment_200 test2_name:null:string q/1
  msg: segment_201 test3_name:null:string foo
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    prefixes: "{{ vms.results|
                  map(attribute='list')|
                  map('map', attribute='prefix')|
                  map('map', 'split', ':')|
                  map('map', 'community.general.dict_kv', 'prefix')|
                  list }}"
    vms_prefixes_str: |
      {% for i in vms.results|map(attribute='list')|zip(prefixes) %}
      - {{ i.0|zip(i.1)|map('combine')|list }}
      {% endfor %}
    vms_prefixes: "{{ vms_prefixes_str|from_yaml|flatten }}"
      
  tasks:

    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/test/{{ item }}/sample.csv
      loop: [csv1, csv2]
      register: vms

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: vms
        - debug:
            var: prefixes|to_yaml
        - debug:
            var: vms_prefixes|to_yaml
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.table_name }} {{ '%-22s' % (item.0.column_name) }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ vms_prefixes }}"
        - prefix
```

---

Q: ***"combine expects dictionaries"***

A: In 2.9 you can't *map* the filer *combine*. Update the declaration of *vms_prefixes_str*

```yaml
    vms_prefixes_str: |
      {% for i in vms.results|map(attribute='list')|zip(prefixes) %}
      {% for a,b in i.0|zip(i.1) %}
      - {{ a|combine(b) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi @Vladimir Botka. I tried the above suggestion. I ma getting the error,

`{"msg": "subelements lookup expects a dictionary, got '<generator object do_map at 0x7f705a076370>'"}`

Please note that I am using Ansible 2.9 `ansible 2.9.9`

Comment: Add the filter *list* both to *prefixes* and to *vms_prefixes_str*. I updated the answer.

Comment: I did try. It still fails
`FAILED! => {"msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got ({u'prefix': u'x:y/1:z/1', u'table_name': u'segment_100', u'column_name': u'test1:null:string'}, u'[')"}`

Comment: In 2.9 you can't *map* the filter *combine*. I added a workaround.

Comment: `Please note that I am using Ansible 2.9 ansible 2.9.9` <= **Please note that this is an obsolete, outdated, unsupported... version and that you _must_ upgrade** => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#ansible-core-support-matrix